# Powershell/Command Line - Turn off password protected sharing

Tags: python, windows, powershell, command-line

I am attempting to create a batch script that will turn off Password Protected Sharing programmatically.

This is for Windows 10 so the code I wrote may have worked for Windows 7.

```
os.system('reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa /v everyoneincludesanonymous /t REG_DWORD /d 0x1 /f')

os.system('reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanManServer\Parameters /v restrictnullsessaccess /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f')
```

Powershell/command line returns, "The operation completed successfully" & the keys have been created in the registry w/ the correct values, name, etc. However, the "Turn on password protected sharing" radio button located in the Advanced sharing settings of the Control Panel is enabled (should be disabled). I have restarted the computer as well, and got the same results.

Comment: Could be just me, but where's the Powershell code?

Comment: Most Windows components read values from registry while _bootup_ and keep it cached. You need to restart to make `HKLM` registry changes take effect.

Comment: My fault. I've been running my script files in Powershell, but the code itself is python/command line. I should have noted in the OP that I restarted, but the radio button is still enabled

Comment: Recommend setting this via GPO rather than script.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart I assume you can do this programmatically? This is crucial as this batch file will be used for Windows setup purposes on numerous machines so I want to automate as much as possible. New to batch scripting/powershell so any guidance would be helpfulp. Thanks! Was this: https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/control/content/microsoft-active-directory-apple-open-directory/how-to-use-a-windows-active-directory-group-policy-object-gpo-to-logon-and-logout-users-automatically-from-kerio-control-917.html what you were referencing to?

Comment: Are you in a domain environment, or do you need to automate system setup without the computers being connected to a domain (OEM style)? In case of the former use GPOs as Bill suggested.

Comment: The latter. Automating NUCs that aren't connected to a domain

Comment: In that case, you should consider configuring the settings as a part of the system image instead of trying to automate after-the-fact.